# xcode sound detection to start app functions

Tags: objective-c

I want to make my app start it's timers when it hears a sound. When you open the app, the timers are ready to start, as soon as someone says "Start", the timers start.

Can someone enlighten me on this one?

Answer (score 1):

A while ago, I read [a question on Quora about this](http://www.quora.com/What-are-the-best-speech-recognition-APIs-for-use-in-iOS-apps).

There are several libraries available to do speech processing on an iOS device:

[OpenEars](http://www.politepix.com/openears/) appears to be a pretty good and popular library. You get some of the features for free and have to pay for more advanced features. This is the only solution I've found that doesn't require an internet connection, but you're limited in scope with your grammar and vocabulary. I think this would work well for your case.

[Nuance Mobile](http://www.quora.com/What-are-the-best-speech-recognition-APIs-for-use-in-iOS-apps) has one as well. I agree with the Quora poster, though, as I was never able to even get registered for this service. Therefore, I was never able to acquire the library and test it. It looks good, but if it's inaccessible, it's not much use. I think this one requires a network connection.

[iSpeech](http://www.ispeech.org/#/home) is another popular one, but I have no experience with it. I think their pricing is a bit steep. Requires internet connection.

[AT&T Speech API](http://developer.att.com/apis/speech) looks pretty good and has multiple platform SDKs available. The pricing on it, however, gets steep pretty quickly, so I shied away from it. Requires internet connection.